# Is setting a div background image really this hard?

Tags: html, css

All I'm trying to do is make a full width div with a background image so that I can nest or put text on top of it.

Here's my div

```
<div class="dpsplash">
</div>
```

And here's the dpsplash class

```
.dpsplash {
    background-image: url('img/banner1.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

There's no other code and for some reason it's not showing the image, am I referencing the url but yeah not sure, here's the site http://deliciousproductions.com.au

If you want a responsive div background image class which keeps the same visible height during screen resizing you can use the class

```
.responsivebg {
    background-image: url('/img/etc..');    
    background-size: auto 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I think it's handy

Comment: The picture is not found at the path `http://deliciousproductions.com.au/css/img/banner1.png`

Comment: Add a `/` infront of the path, just like in my answer I posted below :)

Comment: any reason why it's drawing the width 100% as past 100% in browser? http://deliciousproductions.com.au

Comment: ..."Is setting a div background image really this hard?": No usually it isn't

Answer (score 3):

I would do this instead:

```
.dpsplash {
    background-image: url('/img/banner1.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can use `background-size` as `cover` for the full page.

And notice the `/` added infront of the path so that it refers to the image from the *root*

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll give the answer to you. I used background-size: cover; instead of a width and height but now the image isn't displaying again, and when I fixed the url with my previous code, the image would extend past width=100%? Is there a way I can make the image width 100% and then be able to set whatever height I want for the div and it just crops that ammount of pixels out of the bottom of the image. So a 1000px height div but the image is full width, or a 500px height div but the image is still full width with just the bottom cut off?

Comment: To fix your problem use `background-size: 100% 100%;` instead of `background-size: cover`, that way u manually control the width and size rather than letting the browser decide :)

Comment: It actually needs to be background-size: 100% auto; and then you control the height of the div with height: xxpx; thank you heaps :D

Comment: Hmm so now when I go on mobile, the div goes 400px which is no good if the width goes smaller than the aspect ratio allows the height of the picture to be at full width. Any advice on making the image keep the height point during resizing of the window? so that the width can dynamically chaneg but on mobile the image will take up all the divs height instead of width?

Comment: yay this works. 

.dpsplash {
 background-image: url('/img/banner1.png'); 
 background-size: auto 600px;
 height: 400px;
 background-position: center top;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Comment: hmm is there a way to make the image height automatically what it would need to be for the image to display as full width on the site? Because this .dpsplash {
 background-image: url('/img/banner1.png'); 
 background-size: auto 800px;
 height: 400px;
 background-position: center top;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
background-image: url('img/banner1.png');
```

into this:

```
background-image: url('/img/banner1.png');
```

And you're set.

Answer (score 2):

The link is relative so it is referencing the `img` directory inside of your `css` directory

http://deliciousproductions.com.au/css/img/banner1.png

`background-image: url('../img/banner1.png');`

That should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
.dpsplash {
    background-image: url('../img/banner1.png');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"height: 100vh;" seems as css3 property. Have you checked whether your browser supports it ? Than if div is empty the height will be zero background-image will not be seen. Have you tried to put some text inside div tags ? You may try deleting "height". Div tag should expand when you enter text or content in it.

Answer (score 0):

Background images can be tricky, they mostly end up not being responsive, but this post will help you with that issue.

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/